# How to detect if my Azure SQL Database is in a "Pause" state using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database

How to detect if my Azure SQL Database is in a "Pause" state using C#? I am trying to find some sample code to detect if my SQL Database is "paused"

[image]

Comment: Just curious: why do you care?

Comment: Your database is paused due to lack of activity or a setting. Its gonna be up on next login.

Comment: I know why it's in pause mode I was just wondering if there is a way using c# to detect that. I am just curious what libraries methods could be used to detect this

Comment: @Fildor I am more just curious if there c# libraries that can me more about my azure database environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the REST API through C# to know the status of an Azure SQL database. First, go to the REST API below and generate a Bearer token by running it with the required details:

- [Databases - Get - REST API (Azure SQL Database) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/get?view=rest-sql-2021-11-01&tabs=HTTP#code-try-0)

After that, use the Bearer token in the code below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await CallAzureManagementAPI();
    }

    static async Task CallAzureManagementAPI()
    {
        string subscriptionId = "<subscriptionId>";
        string resourceGroupName = "<resourceGroupName>";
        string serverName = "<serverName>";
        string databaseName = "<databaseName>";
        string apiVersion = "2021-11-01";

        string url = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/databases/{databaseName}?api-version={apiVersion}";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string bearerToken = "<bearerToken>"; // Replace this with your actual Bearer token
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to call Azure Management API. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will get the status of the database as shown below:

[image]